# Responsive Image Hover - CSS/JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, hover, zooming, scale

I followed this tutorial (http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/hover-zoom-effect-with-jquery-and-css/) and built out a image-hover plugin that I'd like to use on my site.

The only problem I have is that I want it to work responsively, scaling the images according to my 960gs.

Here's the fiddle I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Ak94R/6/

```
.viewport {
    float: left;
    height: 360px;
    margin: 0 9px 9px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
```

}

Instead of shrinking that image from 730px/730px to 360px/360px, I want to shrink it from 200% to 100%. I also need the main clipping div (.viewport) to be sized at 100%. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't this be done entirely by CSS? Not sure if you need jQuery at all to be honest.

Comment: `transform: scale(1.5);` and `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-o-`, and `-ms-` for other browsers.

Comment: The problem is, it still needs to be clipped in a div. But I need that div to maintain the same size ratio as the images. Josh Powell - Would you be willing to provide a more detailed example of the "transform:scale(1.5);" you're suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've just spend a few minutes for a [CSS only solution](http://jsfiddle.net/G5CS2/1/). Does the same thing and no JS required. Fully responsive since it works with percentages. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="viewport_css">
    // I have to use a dummy image to force dimensions
    <img class="dummy" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" />
    <a class="imgwrapper" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/730/730/" alt="More Info" />
    </a>
</div>
```

The CSS part:

```
.viewport_css {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 360px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

// make sure viewport_css always is square shaped
.viewport_css .dummy {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.viewport_css a,
.viewport_css a:hover:before,
.viewport_css a:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.viewport_css a,
.viewport_css a:hover:after {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.viewport_css a:hover:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);    
}

.viewport_css a:hover:before {
    content: 'View';
    color: #fff;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 200;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}

.viewport_css .imgwrapper {
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    margin-top: -50%;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;  
}

.viewport_css .imgwrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.viewport_css .imgwrapper:hover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very close! The only problem I'm still having is with:.viewport_css {width: 360px; height: 360px;}

How can I make this percentage based as well? I tried max-width:360px; width:100%; and it works, but the height's still off.

Comment: You need some kind of container to set dimensions. You could do something with a dummy image which has visibility: hidden on it. In that case you only need a width on the viewport_css element (and the max-width + width as you mentioned should do the trick).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean with the dummy image. Are you able to expand at all?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle and the code example above. Added a base64 encoded transparent 1x1 GIF image to the source. If someone knows a better alternative without polluting the DOM please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I altered `background-size: 70px 80px;` using media queries at each break point - this resolved the issue for me