# Responsive Image Hover and Zoom with Words

Tags: html, css

[Responsive Image Hover - CSS/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081908/responsive-image-hover-css-jquery)

I would like to do the same as Eric Wood who asked the question above, and the answer given was great- it really helped me. The only problem is that I want text to show when you hover over the image. And right now my text is moving along with the image. I want the text to show and stay exactly the way it popped up, while the image keeps zooming out. Can anyone help me?

Here's the code (I used bootstrap, so col-md-3 means that on a medium screen it takes up 3 out of 12 sections of the grid, and col-xs-6 means it takes up 6 out of 12, meaning that the divs are in percentages/responsive):

HTML:

```
<div class="lg-20p col-md-3 col-xs-6 recreation-box">
    <img class="recreation-dummy-img" src="images/dummy.png" alt="" />
    <a class="imgwrapper" href="#">
        <span>
        <h4>Alpine Slide</h4>
        <p>Hop on your sled and cruise down an exhilarating half mile of     twisting, turning track back to the base.</p>
        </span>
        <img src="images/alpine.jpg" alt="Alpine Slide" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.recreation-box {
position: relative;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
}
.recreation-box .recreation-dummy-img{
width: 100%;
height:auto;
display:block;
}

.recreation-box a,
.recreation-box a:hover:before,
.recreation-box a:hover:after {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
right:0px;
}

.recreation-box a,
.recreation-box a:hover:after {
top:0;
bottom:0;
}

.recreation-box a:hover:after {
content:'';
display:block;
z-index: 100;
background-color: rgba(1, 67, 74, .7);
}

.recreation-box a:hover:before{
content: '';
color: #fff;
top:40%;
text-align:center;
z-index:200;
margin-top:-0.5em;
}
.recreation-box a span{
display:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
height:70%;
width:80%;
top:15%;
left:10%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
position:absolute;
text-align:left;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
z-index:300;
color:white;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.recreation-box a:hover span{
display:block;
}
.recreation-box .recreation-inner span h4{
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.recreation-box a span p{
font-size:14px;
font-weight:normal;
}
.recreation-box .imgwrapper {
width: 115%;
height: 115%;
margin-left: -5%;
margin-top: -5%;
transition: all .2s ease-in;  
}

.recreation-box .imgwrapper img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}

.recreation-box .imgwrapper:hover {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
.lg-20p{
width:20%;
}
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? It's hard to understand what's going without an example

Comment: Sorry, I just added the code above. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't able to get that code working...try putting it on jsfiddle or codepen to show me a working version.